# How to detect if device is a Samsung device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, device, samsung-mobile

Is it possible to detect if device is a Samsung device?
I would like to show  for all other devices and for Samsung devices  because of the missing decimal point on some Samsung devices.

Comment: Missing decimal point? You mean in the on-screen keyboard, or are you talking about a phone with actual pushbuttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the Cordova Device Plugin:

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.device

Run:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

And in your code:

```
console.log(device.model);
```

There is also available with ngCordova:
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/

Comment: WARNING: device.name is deprecated as of version 2.3.0. Use device.model instead.

Comment: Moreover org.apache.cordova.device is deprecated for cordova-plugin-device

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the constructor name with cordova & ionic.

However, you can have access to the model of the device : http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/

If you manage Samsung device list and compare it to `getModel()` value you can know therefore if the device is a samsung or not.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted the other answer because it´s more detailed.